# iOS with cocos2d to MVC or not to MVC?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, design-patterns

I am working with cocos2d.

All my objects are declared on the `CCLayer` that I'm using, I have the logic of the game there and all the `CCSprites`.

Should I put the `CCSprite` for the player and all it's related properties (HP, Velocity, etc) in a Player object and then have that player object in my `CCLayer`?

But then how to add the `CCSprite` of the player to the `CCLayer`? Should I put in the `CCLayer` this?:

```
[self addChild:[PlayerObject playerSprite]];
```

Or should I create a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a matter of preference. Depending on the type of game, the MVC architecture might be a good fit, sometimes/mostly it will feel out of place though. I have used it for puzzle games before (eg. your board is the model, the controller handles user input and makes the changes on the board and a view that renders these changes).

Another architecture that works well for game development is the [component pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html). Your approach even goes into that direction, because you have a `Player` object and add a `Sprite` component added to it. Depending on the scale of your game and flexibility you need, you might even want to go further and have a basic `Entity` class and components that define the entities look/behavior etc. And when you make this data-driven, then the real fun starts :)

Generally, I'd try to separate your game-logic as much as possible from your drawing API (in this case cocos2d). If you wanted to port your game to another platform/engine, then you'll have to separate all your code from the engine API anyway.

So instead of having a `CCLayer` that instantiates your player, rather have some sort of `Controller` that creates the `CCLayer` and your entities and adds them to the layer.